# Wrong coordinate in android chrome pointer event

Tags: android, html, google-chrome, pointer-events

Steps to reproduce the problem:

1. Open the html(https://ufile.io/9186t) in android chrome browser.
2. Touch anywhere on the page. You will be getting clientY coordinates appended in the div.
3. I have appended clientY coordinates for both "touchstart" and "pointerdown" event. You can see the clientY coordinates. The pointerdown event is having wrong clientY coordinates and ideally both coordinates should have been same.

What is the expected behavior?
The clientY coordinates in the pointer down event should be correct.

What went wrong?
Wrong value of clientY coordinates in the "pointerdown" event.

Did this work before? Yes

Does this work in other browsers? Yes

Chrome version: 64.0.3282.137  Channel: n/a
OS Version: 6.0.1

Comment: I noticed exactly same behavior on desktop Chrome when switching to touch emulation mode in the built-in dev tools.